# Python prometheus metrics , integrate with docker running flask apps

Tags: python, docker, web-applications, prometheus

First of all i am a beginner at web app programming.I have 2 Flask apps that communicate with each other that i start using docker-compose up -d.

How can i integrate prometheus metrics with those apps? I have used prometheus_client  lib for prometheus but the  command  start_http_server(9000) doesn't work because the localhost:9000 is Unable to connect (when i run start_http_server with a python script outside of docker it works though).

Is there a way to get the prometheus image and set it up so that the other apps in docker-compose communicate their metrics with prometheus?